# How to change ID attribute of Episerver Forms form element?

Tags: episerver, episerver-forms

I'm using Episerver Forms with CMS 11.

I would like to change the default `id` attribute on the `form` element to render a custom ID instead of the form GUID:

```
<form id="6d670961-57db-4935-8876-8a730f37c468">
```

Is there a way to change it to a custom (but still unique) name so that I can insert an anchor tag which scrolls to the form with an SEO-friendly URL?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JohanPetersson: Basically, I have a hyperlink (http://mydomain#formGuid) at top of page. when user click on that link, user is navigated within page to that form.

Now, for SEO purpose, http://mydomain#formGuid is not user friendly URL. So, I was trying to achieve like http://mydomain#formName.  But for this, EPiServer forms  needs to be rendered with id =formName  instead of   id =formGuid.  Hope, you get my requirement.

Comment: You can change the rendering by overriding the view for FormContainer and wrap the form with a div with your id instead. I'm pretty sure the current id is needed. This blog should help you https://swapcode.wordpress.com/2019/03/24/create-custom-episerver-forms-container/.

Comment: @JohanPetersson: Thanks... I tried overriding FormContainer with id=formName but was wondering that should not break anything as might required by episerver forms internally (default value). I think, your suggestion is good to wrap in div so that it wont break anything.